# how to create background thread in WP7 with timeout?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm using Mango, so I have background tasks.
How can I make the thread that will process the data?(with timeout)
I need to create thread for checking incoming messages.I need to set timeout for it.Thread must running in background on all pages.

I want something like

```
     public startApp() { 
     Thread th = new Thread(function_to_check,5)//last is  timeout 
}
```

Comment: What, exactly, should the timeout do?  If the thread doesn't exit normally in that time it should abort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) in your App.xaml.cs file.

...

```
private static readonly DispatcherTimer myTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
 myTimer .Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            myTimer .Tick += myTimerTick;
            myTimer .Start();
```

...

```
 private void myTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //do something here
        }
```

edit:

This allows you a single location to do what you want. If you need custom logic per page, you could create a `switch` statement where you check the current page

Or you could override `PhoneApplicationPage` with a page where you create this timer, and override the `Tick` function in each subpage.